# How allow a set of IPs and deny everything else? (.htaccess and apache 2.4)

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I need allow internet access from a set of IPs and deny everything else.

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
<RequireAll>
  Require all denied
  Require ip x.x.x.x/xx y.y.y.y/yy
</RequireAll>
```

this:

```
<RequireAll>
  Require all denied
  Require ip x.x.x.x/xx
  Require ip y.y.y.y/yy
</RequireAll>
```

and this:

```
<RequireAny>
  Require ip x.x.x.x/xx y.y.y.y/yy
</RequireAll>
```

also this:

```
Require all denied
Require ip x.x.x.x/xx
Require ip y.y.y.y/yy
```

I couldn't find the correct way to do the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require ip x.x.x.x
    Require ip y.y.y.y
    Require ip z.z.z.z
</RequireAny>
```